# Sequence extraction in a dataset

Tags: python, sequential-pattern-mining

I am looking for a way to extract sequences/patterns from a dataset such as this one:

```
dataset = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample3', 'sample2'...]
```

And my goal is to know that the sequence ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'] occurs 2 times in this dataset.
Ideally, I would also like to know all sequences that occur more than once in my dataset.

Is there a library (sklearn...) that could help me do that or do I just have to iterate over my dataset and test each and every possible combination? I assume there must be a more intelligent way to do that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nltk.util.ngrams` for ngram extraction. 
See an example below:

### To extract bigrams:

```
dataset = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3',\ 
'sample3', 'sample2', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample1', 'sample2']

from nltk.util import ngrams
import collections

bigrams = ngrams(dataset, 2)
result = collections.Counter(bigrams)
result.most_common()

Out[1]: 
[(('sample1', 'sample2'), 3),
 (('sample2', 'sample3'), 3),
 (('sample3', 'sample1'), 2),
 (('sample3', 'sample3'), 1),
 (('sample3', 'sample2'), 1),
 (('sample2', 'sample2'), 1)]
```

### To extract trigrams:

```
trigrams = ngrams(dataset, 3)
result = collections.Counter(trigrams)
result.most_common()

Out[2]: 
[(('sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'), 2),
 (('sample2', 'sample3', 'sample1'), 2),
 (('sample3', 'sample1', 'sample2'), 2),
 (('sample2', 'sample3', 'sample3'), 1),
 (('sample3', 'sample3', 'sample2'), 1),
 (('sample3', 'sample2', 'sample2'), 1),
 (('sample2', 'sample2', 'sample3'), 1)]
```

### Fourgrams:

```
fourgrams = ngrams(dataset, 4)
result = collections.Counter(fourgrams)
result.most_common()

Out[3]: 
[(('sample2', 'sample3', 'sample1', 'sample2'), 2),
 (('sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample1'), 1),
 (('sample3', 'sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'), 1),
 (('sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample3'), 1),
 (('sample2', 'sample3', 'sample3', 'sample2'), 1),
 (('sample3', 'sample3', 'sample2', 'sample2'), 1),
 (('sample3', 'sample2', 'sample2', 'sample3'), 1),
 (('sample2', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample1'), 1)]
 ...
```

You only need to specify the length of your n-grams and what number of repetitions is representative in your case.

Hope this helps!